# SQL statement problem with count

Tags: sql

I have a SQL statement which returns:

```
AUFTRNR     MITARBNAME      GESAMTDIFFERENZ
  2           Schmidt               5
  2           Schmidt             -20
  2           Schmidt               0
  2           Schmidt              -5
  2           Schmidt               5
```

but I need:

```
AUFTRNR    MITARBNAME      GESAMTDIFFERENZ
   2         Schmidt              -20
```

that mean: I need something that count me the values from the "GESAMTDIFFERENZ"
(5 + -20 + -5 + 0 + -5 + 5)

My Code:

```
select arbeitsauftrag.AUFTRNR, mitarbeiter.MITARBNAME, (arbeitszeit.ISTZEIT-arbeitsgang.SOLLZEIT) Gesamtdifferenz from ARBEITSAUFTRAG,MITARBEITER,ARBEITSGANG,ARBEITSZEIT where
arbeitsauftrag.FERTIGDATUM IS NOT NULL and arbeitsauftrag.MITARBNR=mitarbeiter.MITARBNR 
and ARBEITSGANG.TEILNR=ARBEITSAUFTRAG.TEILNR 
and ARBEITSGANG.AGNR=ARBEITSZEIT.AGNR 
and ARBEITSZEIT.AUFTRNR=ARBEITSAUFTRAG.AUFTRNR
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply add a `GROUP BY MITARBNAME` to your SQL:

```
select 
     arbeitsauftrag.AUFTRNR, mitarbeiter.MITARBNAME, 
     SUM(arbeitszeit.ISTZEIT-arbeitsgang.SOLLZEIT) Gesamtdifferenz 
from ARBEITSAUFTRAG, MITARBEITER, ARBEITSGANG, ARBEITSZEIT 
where
   arbeitsauftrag.FERTIGDATUM IS NOT NULL 
   and arbeitsauftrag.MITARBNR=mitarbeiter.MITARBNR 
   and ARBEITSGANG.TEILNR=ARBEITSAUFTRAG.TEILNR 
   and ARBEITSGANG.AGNR=ARBEITSZEIT.AGNR 
   and ARBEITSZEIT.AUFTRNR=ARBEITSAUFTRAG.AUFTRNR
GROUP BY
   mitarbeiter.MITARBNAME
```

Also, to avoid unwanted / unexpected cartesian products, I would *strongly* recommend to get away from the old-style JOIN syntax that you have - instead use explicit ANSI-style `INNER JOIN` expressions (and I'd also start using *table aliases* to make things easier and more readable):

```
FROM 
    ARBEITSAUFTRAG aa
INNER JOIN
    MITARBEITER m ON aa.MITARBNR = m.MITARBNR 
INNER JOIN
    ARBEITSGANG ag ON ag.TEILNR = aa.TEILNR 
INNER JOIN
    ARBEITSZEIT az ON ag.AGNR = az.AGNR 
                   AND az.AUFTRNR = aa.AUFTRNR
where
   arbeitsauftrag.FERTIGDATUM IS NOT NULL
```

It also makes your WHERE clause much easier to read!

Answer (score 1):

```
select arbeitsauftrag.AUFTRNR, mitarbeiter.MITARBNAME, SUM(arbeitszeit.ISTZEIT-arbeitsgang.SOLLZEIT) Gesamtdifferenz 
from ARBEITSAUFTRAG,MITARBEITER,ARBEITSGANG,ARBEITSZEIT 
where
   arbeitsauftrag.FERTIGDATUM IS NOT NULL and arbeitsauftrag.MITARBNR=mitarbeiter.MITARBNR 
   and ARBEITSGANG.TEILNR=ARBEITSAUFTRAG.TEILNR 
   and ARBEITSGANG.AGNR=ARBEITSZEIT.AGNR 
   and ARBEITSZEIT.AUFTRNR=ARBEITSAUFTRAG.AUFTRNR
GROUP BY arbeitsauftrag.AUFTRNR, mitarbeiter.MITARBNAME
```

Comment: yeah... thanks at first i tried it with group by arbeitsauftrag.AUFTRNR. That doesn´t work. why i need a second.?

Comment: You have to specify all of the columns that are grouped by.  If you only group by `AUFTRNR`, you would need to say `MAX(MITARBNAME)` or `MIN(MITARBNAME)` in the SELECT clause, so that it knows what to do if more than one value comes back for that field.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
select arbeitsauftrag.AUFTRNR, mitarbeiter.MITARBNAME, sum(arbeitszeit.ISTZEIT-arbeitsgang.SOLLZEIT) Gesamtdifferenz from ARBEITSAUFTRAG,MITARBEITER,ARBEITSGANG,ARBEITSZEIT where
arbeitsauftrag.FERTIGDATUM IS NOT NULL and arbeitsauftrag.MITARBNR=mitarbeiter.MITARBNR 
and ARBEITSGANG.TEILNR=ARBEITSAUFTRAG.TEILNR 
and ARBEITSGANG.AGNR=ARBEITSZEIT.AGNR 
and ARBEITSZEIT.AUFTRNR=ARBEITSAUFTRAG.AUFTRNR
group by arbeitsauftrag.AUFTRNR, mitarbeiter.MITARBNAME
```

?

Comment: yeah... thanks
at first i tried it with group by arbeitsauftrag.AUFTRNR.
That doesn´t work. why i need a second.?